# How to remove wine internet explorer option from Open with menu?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

I use Xubuntu 12.04.1 LTS  (xfce) with Thunar file manager.

[image]

I ran this command:

```
rm ~/.local/share/applications/wine-extension-jpe.desktop
```

And one Wine context menu item has gone.

How do I remove the other one?

Answer (score 6):

I see from your screenshot that you have right clicked an image file (because of the options presented in the context menu), and presumably it is a jpeg or jpg file, as you say you have removed `wine-extension-jpe-desktop`, and that has prevented one of the wine 'open in internet explorer' options from appearing when a jpeg is right-clicked. The other file that you want to remove is `wine-extension-jfif.desktop`, and then no `wine` options will appear when you right click a jpeg or a jpg.

If you take a look at the [w3 standards page](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/), you can see that jpeg jfif is known as the JPEG File Interchange Format; it is known as a progressive jpeg that is heavily compressed. Much more information and technical specifications is available in the [official jfif pdf](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/jfif3.pdf).

If you want other image extensions not to appear in the context menu as well, remove also `wine-extension-gif.desktop` and `wine-extension-png.desktop` from `~/.local/share/applications`. You can easily reassociate a wine program as an option with which to open these filetypes through the 'open with' dialogue or set as default via, for example, `mimeopen -d mypicture.jpeg`. Although very few users probably use `wine` programs to view images or edit them when excellent native Linux based programs are available.

Answer (score 5):

Look in `~/.local/share/applications/`, possibly delete all files that seem related to the applications involved, especially `mimeinfo.cache`.

Comment: worked in elementaryos :)